# Select second child with AngularJS's ng-repeat

Tags: jquery, angularjs, symfony

I am using a bundle in my Symfony2 app, which is using Angular in it's markup:

```
...some table structure

<th ng-repeat="column in columns" ng-show="column.visible">
    <input ng-if="column.filter != false" ng-model="params.filter()[column.index]" type="text" name="{{ column.index }}" value="" class="form-control input-sm" />
</th>
```

I am not allowed to change the code of this bundle, but I need to select `input` of the second `th` of this ng-repeat (I use jQuery). It's name in input element is `name="_domain"`. I managed to select all the inputs:

```
$('#translation-grid table thead tr th input')
```

But neither this:

```
$('#translation-grid table thead tr th input[name=_domain]')
```

Or this:

```
$('#translation-grid table thead tr th:nth-child(2) input')
```

...is working. I only found solutions that required change of the angular markup, but I cannot do this. I just need to select this `input`.

Comment: Where/when are you executing this code? Maybe the `ng-repeat` hasn't been executed yet (and thus no second `th` element)

Comment: Have you tried jQuery's [.eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) function? Could also use the built in Angular `$index`.

Comment: @null - Yes, the code is fully executed, the tables are built completely, all the `th` elements are rendered. As I mentioned, I am able to select all the inputs and give them some `id` for example. Also, when I select `th:first-child index`, it selects the `input` elements in all `th` elements, not just the first one. I think this might be the problem, angular somehow making all the `ng-repeat` subjects act as if they were first children, thus I am unable to select just the secon one...

Comment: @enjoibp3 - Yes, I tried `.eq()` and other jQuery methods of selection (`find()`, `children()`...). I haven't tried the `$index`. Where would I use it in my example? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the jquery selector. What I meant in the comments was that it's probably executing too early (before the `ng-repeat` / `ng-if` / `and-what-else-you-are-using-on-the-page` has finished).

Open the page, open a console and type something like `$('#translation-grid table thead tr th input').css('background-color', 'yellow')`. If that works you almost certainly execute the selector too soon. 
Another easy way to check if this is the case, is by inserting a simple `alert` before the selector. This will block the current *digest* and if the table isn't rendered in the *DOM* at that moment then jquery is also not able to locate it.

If you're executing this in a directive, you might want to try moving it to the **post** `link` function or set the `priority` to a **negative** value. Otherwise try wrapping it into a `$timeout` call without a delay set, which will queue your statement till after the current *digest* cycle has finished.

```
$timeout(function() {
    $('#translation-grid table thead tr th input')
      .css('background-color', 'yellow');
});
```

## Example

The example below tries to highlite 4 columns.

1. Directly in the controller: doesn't work
2. With a queued $timeout: works
3. Directly from the directive: doesn't work
4. From the UI by clinking the button: works

Plunker can be found [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/RztjbhR2v67aLqex7yJg?p=preview).

```js
// Code goes here

function highlite(index, color) {
  alert('Trying to highlite column ' + index + ' with color ' + color);
  $('.table th:nth-child(' + index + ')').css('background-color', color);
}

var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MyController', function($scope) {

  $scope.columns = [
    'First Name', 'Last Name', 'Username', 'Age', 'Sex'
  ];

  $scope.rows = [
    ['Mark', 'Otto', '@mdo', 10, true],
    ['Jacob', 'Thornton', '@fat', 20, false],
    ['Larry', 'the Bird', '@twitter', 30, true]
  ];

  // Expose highlite function to view 

  $scope.highlite = highlite;

  // This does not work; both the directive template and the ng-repeat
  // hasn't been executed yet.

  highlite(1, 'purple');

});

app.directive('myTable', function($timeout) {

  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    template: '<table class="table">' +
                '<thead>' +
                  '<tr>' +
                    '<th ng-repeat="column in columns">{{ column }}</th>' +
                  '</tr>' +
                '</thead>' +
                '<tbody>' +
                  '<tr ng-repeat="row in rows">' +
                    '<td ng-repeat="field in row">' +
                      '{{ field }}' +
                    '</td>' +
                  '</tr>' +
                '</tbody>' +
              '</table>',
    scope: {
      columns: '=',
      rows: '='
    },
    link: function($scope, $element) {

      // This won't work either; the ng-repeat hasn't fired yet

      highlite(3, 'blue');

      // ... but this will: queue the provided function to execute when
      // the current digest cycle has been finished (after the ng-repeat).

      $timeout(function() {
        highlite(4, 'orange');
      });
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" 
      href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.6/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyController" class="container">
  <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>

  <my-table columns="columns" 
            rows="rows">
  </my-table>

  <!-- 
    This will work because the select statement is 
    executed after the ng-repeat has finisched 
  -->
  
  <button class="btn btn-primary" 
          ng-click="highlite(2, 'yellow')">
    Click me!
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: The example is very nice, thank you for the time and effort you put into it. But I am building a Symfony app, not Angular app. Angular is only used in a 3rd party bundle I have to use, for rendering this translations table. I cannot modify this bundle and in my app I only call it's internal render methods, which use angular within themselves. Right now, I managed to select the input by wrapping it in `$(document).ready()`, then it worked. But the tbody rows are rendered by another `ng-repeat` with a template, and this happens after the `$(document).ready()`. Now I can't select those :D

Comment: I have accepted your answer, since the problem really was with executing the select too early. I cannot apply the solution as you propose, but that is another topic. I'm finding out that executing any JS code AFTER the Angular DOM is ready, but WITHOUT the Angular Directive, is almost an impossible task...

Answer (score 0):

Why not `$('#translation-grid table thead tr th input')[1]` ? Since you are able to select all elements, you are also able to pick one in the array.

To use $index requires modifying your angular by including a custom data attribute, such as `data-index="{{$index}}"`. This would assign the data-index attribute to the element with the value equal to the index in the ng-repeat loop, so you could refer to this attribute in your jquery with the expression `$('#translation-grid table thead tr th input[data-index=1]')`.